# MVC. Setting data in View

Tags: ios, objective-c, model-view-controller

[image]

**View** does not know about the **model**. I have custom view:

```
@interface CustomView : UIView

@property UIImageView *imageView;
@property UILabel *labelView;
@property UILabel *dateLabelView;
@property UIImageView *badgeView;

...

@end
```

Set data in ViewController:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
     ...
    //Install data from model in view
    self.customView.labelView.text = self.model.title;
    self.customView.badgeView.hidden = self.model.isBadge;
    self.customView.dateLabelView.text = [self formatDate:self.model.createDate];
     ...
}
```

How to use CustomView in other ViewControllers, without having to copy code and or creating the following method in the class CustomView:

```
- (void)setData:(id)data;
```

because **View** does not know about the **model**.

Comment: What exactly is your question? How to get data from model to View?

Comment: How correctly get data from model to view in mvc

Comment: What is model? A singleton? A backing store? An object?

Comment: this example model is nsobject. but it does not matter

Comment: Why do you think your code is wrong/bad? For me it seems pretty normal - you're setting view's props from model's data. That is what controllers for.

Comment: dmirkitanov, i think this code is superfluity, because if i have 3 different viewControllers, each uses the same code

Comment: and i do not want create method - (void)setData:(id)data; in class view, because model may vary

Comment: using setData: to communicate model to a view is a correct way, but your raison that the "View does not know about the model" its incorrect

Comment: using setData: to communicate model to a view is a correct way, but the view needs to know the model (data type, attributes..) in order to read from it correctly but not to change it as MVC stats. In ordre to re-use the view for different Models (from diff ViewController), you need as you expected to rewrite the code in each viewController(safe) or to handle Models inside setData: using introspection [modelObject isKindOfClass:[ModelClassA class]]

Comment: another way is to use a ViewController for your  "shared" view. this ViewController declare a Protocol, each ViewController who want to use the view should implement that protocol to communicate model.